# How to write a constructor that contains a boolean value?

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

This is a dumb question but it's been a long time since I've worked with java...  How can I write my constructor with Boolean values or should I just write a default constructor?  I have been working with C++ most recently and I've forgotten a lot of syntax for java.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Creature {
    protected int terrain;
    public static final int DESERT = 0;
    public static final int MOUNTAIN = 1;
    public static final int FOREST = 2;

    //symbols on cards
    boolean flyingCreature = false;
    boolean magicCreature = false;
    boolean canCharge = false;
    boolean rangedCombat false;
    public int specialAbility = 0;

    public Creature(int startTerrain, boolean flying, boolean magic, boolean charge, boolean ranged, int special){
        ?
    }   
}
```

I can't seem to find anything when I do a search... How do I initialize each value in my constructor?  or should I just have

```
public Creature(){
    startTerrain = DESERT;
    flyingCreature = false;
    magicCreature = false;
    canCharge = false;
    specialAbility = 0;
} ?
```

I also have several classes inheriting from this one, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure why your issue is specific to booleans?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write my constructor

Comment: I would create each field you need, don't give them a value and let the IDE generate the rest, constructors, getters and any setters.  You don't have to write all this code yourself.

Comment: BTW You are not using `Boolean` anywhere, just `boolean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean parameter is just like any other type.

So, it would be like this.

```
public Creature(int startTerrain, boolean flying, boolean magic, boolean charge, boolean ranged, int special){
        terrain = startTerrain;
        flyingCreature = flying;
        magicCreature = magic;
        canCharge = charge;
        rangedCombat = ranged;
        specialAbility = special;
}
```

If these parameters are going to be always the same on the beggining, then you can set them on a default constructor, as you said.

Since, you have classes inheriting this one, their constructor will have to call `super()`, which calls the parent class constructor. If you call it without any parameters, the base constructor of Creature will be called.

Comment: Thank you!  It's a little confusing going from C++ to java

Answer (score 4):

If you use the constructor which has parameters, it goes like this

```
this.flyingCreature = flying;
this.magicCreature = magic;
```

and so on.

If you use the constructor without any parameters (the default constructor), then you need to set the class fields to some constants (like you did). So you do e.g.

```
this.flyingCreature = false;
this.magicCreature = false;
```

and so on.

The use of `this.` is not mandatory unless you have a parameter with the same name in which case you should use `this.` otherwise your initialization code will have no effect on the class field.

Answer (score 2):

You probably appropriately chose the primitive type boolean in your example but since you mentioned "Boolean" with a capital "B", there is a difference.  Boolean variables are nullable unlike the primitive "boolean" with a lower case "b".  If you had used Booleans, you can simply initialize those like

```
Boolean boolVar = Boolean.TRUE; //or Boolean.FALSE
```

And they might later require null checks depending on the situation.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference, my browser underlined boolean saying I had spelled it wrong, so I figured that I must need the capital B.  It is interesting to know that there is actually a difference between the two.

Comment: You are welcome, most primitive types in Java have Object based types, Integer for int, Double for double, etc.